# How do i remove the whitespace?

Tags: java, eclipse, string

I'm trying to create a palindrome tester program for my AP Java class and I need to remove the white spaces in my code completely but it's not letting me do so.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Palin{

  public static boolean isPalindrome(String stringToTest) {
    String workingCopy = removeJunk(stringToTest);
    String reversedCopy = reverse(workingCopy);

    return reversedCopy.equalsIgnoreCase(workingCopy);
  }

  public static String removeJunk(String string) {
    int i, len = string.length();
    StringBuffer dest = new StringBuffer(len);
    char c;


    for (i = (len - 1); i >= 0; i-=1) {
      c = string.charAt(i);
      if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(c)) 
      {
        dest.append(c);
      }


    }

    return dest.toString();
  }

  public static String reverse(String string) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(string);

    return sb.reverse().toString();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print("Enter Palindrome: ");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String string = sc.next();

    String str = string;
    String space = "";
    String result = str.replaceAll("\\W", space);
    System.out.println(result);

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Testing palindrome:");
    System.out.println("    " + string);
    System.out.println();

    if (isPalindrome(result)) {
      System.out.println("It's a palindrome!");
    } else {
      System.out.println("Not a palindrome!");
    }
    System.out.println();
  }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your code is fine except for the following. You are using

```
String string = sc.next();
```

which will not read the whole line of input, hence you will lose part of the text. I think you should use the following instead of that line.

```
String string = sc.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to remove the beginning and ending whitespace, you can use the built in function trim(), e.g. " abcd ".trim() is "abcd"
If you want to remove it everywhere, you can use the replaceAll() method with the whitespace class as the parameter, e.g. " abcd ".replaceAll("\W","").

Answer (score 0):

Use a StringTokenizer to remove `" "`

```
  StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(string," ",false);
  String t="";
  while (st.hasMoreElements()) t += st.nextElement();
  String result = t;
  System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: This should replace your `replaceAll` block

Comment: But, should also work with `replaceAll("\\W", "")` and `replaceAll("\\s+", "")`

Comment: Import `java.util.StringTokenizer`. Which java version do you use ?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't actually tesed this, but have you considered the [String.replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method?

```
public static String removeJunk (String string) {
    return string.replaceAll (" ", "");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to look out for is that while removing all non-digit/alpha characters `removeJunk` also reverses the string (it starts from the end and then appends one character at a time).

So after reversing it again (in `reverse`) you are left with the original and it will always claim that the given string is a palindrome.

Comment: Ah, nevermind - just noticed that you compare `reversedCopy` to `workingCopy` and not `stringToTest`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `String` `replace(char oldChar, char newChar)` method.
Although the name suggests that only the first occurrence will be replaced, [fact is](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) that all occurrences will be replaced. The advantage of this method is that it won't use regular expressions, thus is more efficient.

So give a try to `string.replace(' ', '');`